# HDMI sound output in 17.10 - conflict with screensaver

Tags: sound, hdmi, screensaver

my PC has two sound output, HDMI and built-in speaker. I have set HDMI as the default output, but it keeps switching to the other one every time the screen is turned off by the screensaver.

Is there any way to prevent this other than disabling the screensaver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns off the VPN Connection too, I suspect this is a bug. Gonna up-vote this.

Comment: What happens when you disable the screensaver? Is the problem solved?

Comment: If you turn off the screen saver it defeats the whole purpose along with disabling hibernate. No Power saving/screen.